# How to draw interior buffer or interior stroke on a polygon with OpenLayers 4

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, cartography

I'd like to recreate the same style that OSM use when editing polygons. I'm calling it an 'interior stroke' or 'interior buffer'.

OSM example:

[image]

I know that I can use an array of `ol.style.Style`, with one sending back `geometry` for the interior buffer. However it seems really resource intensive to create new geometries simply to represent the original geometry with a buffer. Is that the recommended way? Can I use `ol.style.Stroke` in some advanced manner?

---

An additional feature is that the **screen pixel width** of the 'interior stroke' is a constant amount, irrespective of zoom level. For example, here's that polygon zoomed out and in:

[image: Zoomed out]
[image: Zoomed in]

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to what I have used in my project. I got this piece of code from http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.style.html If you want a thicker border, you can increase the width in stroke.

```
var fill = new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.4)'
});
var stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: '#3399CC',
    width: 1.25
});
var style = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: fill,
    stroke: stroke
});
```

Comment: Just using a stroke with a width places the stroke pixels directly in the center of the actual coordinates, not on the interior like I'm asking. I'm looking for a way to say:  "draw the stroke *inside* the shape, not *on* the border"

Comment: If you want to draw inside the shape, then I guess you will have to use 2 polygons. I looked at the API. Did not find anything that could solve your problem with a single polygon.